# C# Newton.Json deserialize

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I would like to read a xml and convert json and then convert that json to an C# object.
Bare in mind that i could use linq to initialize the objects, i know that.
But what i want to a achieve is read the xml convert it to json and from the converted string Deserialize to object. I'm not being able to initialize correctly the object.
What am i missing?

```
public class Cash
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public class POSLog
{
    public string MajorVersion { get; set; }
    public string MinorVersion { get; set; }
    public string FixVersionive { get; set; }

    public Cash Cashx { get; set; }   
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml("<POSLog MajorVersion=\"6\" MinorVersion=\"0\" FixVersion=\"0\"><Cash Amount = \"100\"></Cash></POSLog>");

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xml.InnerXml);

            POSLog deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<POSLog>(json);

            Console.WriteLine("Major Version" + deserializedProduct.MajorVersion);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not convert straight from xml to object?

Comment: Does it serialize your json correctly?

Comment: You also have the naming of the variable in `POSLog` as `FixVersionive` which does not match the naming in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation :

**[Converting between JSON and XML with Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)**

> **Conversion Rules**
>
> - Elements remain unchanged.
> - **Attributes are prefixed with an @ and should be at the start of the object.**
> - Single child text nodes are a value directly against an element, otherwise they are accessed via #text.
> - The XML declaration and processing instructions are prefixed with ?.
> - Character data, comments, whitespace and significant whitespace nodes are accessed via #cdata-section, #comment, #whitespace and #significant-whitespace respectively.
> - Multiple nodes with the same name at the same level are grouped together into an array.
> - Empty elements are null.
>
> If the XML created from JSON doesn't match what you want, then you will need to convert it manually. The best approach to do this is to load your JSON into a LINQ to JSON object like JObject or JArray and then use LINQ to create an XDocument.

With that in mind the following unit test created to solve your problem passes.

```
[TestClass]
public class JsonToXmlTests : MiscUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Xml_Should_Convert_To_JSON_And_Object() {

        string xml = "<POSLog MajorVersion=\"6\" MinorVersion=\"0\" FixVersion=\"0\"><Cash Amount = \"100\"></Cash></POSLog>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

        //Attributes are prefixed with an @ and should be at the start of the object.
        jsonText = jsonText.Replace("\"@", "\"");

        POSLog actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<POSLog>(jsonText);

        actual.Should().NotBeNull();
        actual.MajorVersion.Should().Be("6");
        actual.MinorVersion.Should().Be("0");
        actual.FixVersion.Should().Be("0");
        actual.Cash.Should().NotBeNull();
        actual.Cash.Amount.Should().Be("100");
    }

    public class Cash {
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class POSLog {
        public string MajorVersion { get; set; }
        public string MinorVersion { get; set; }
        public string FixVersion { get; set; }

        public Cash Cash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize a `string` containing `xml` into `json` and expect it to deserialize into a `POSLog`. Deserialized your xml into a `POSLog` before you continue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're deserializing the wrong thing.

You have to first deserialize to POSLog from XML and then serialize the POSLog as json.

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        string xmlDoc = "<POSLog MajorVersion=\"6\" MinorVersion=\"0\" FixVersion=\"0\"><Cash Amount = \"100\"></Cash></POSLog>";

        XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(POSLog));
        POSLog fromXml = xser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlDoc)) as POSLog;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fromXml); 

        POSLog fromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<POSLog>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("MajorVersion=" + fromJson.MajorVersion);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Cash
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

public class POSLog
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MajorVersion { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MinorVersion { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FixVersionive { get; set; }

    public Cash Cashx { get; set; }
}
```